# Regex split numbers and letter groups without spaces

Tags: java, regex

If I have a string like "11E12C108N" which is a concatenation of letter groups and digit groups, how do I split them without a delimiter space character inbetween?

For example, I want the resulting split to be:

```
tokens[0] = "11"
tokens[1] = "E"
tokens[2] = "12"
tokens[3] = "C"
tokens[4] = "108"
tokens[5] = "N"
```

I have this right now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String stringToSplit = "11E12C108N";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\D+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToSplit);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Which gives me:

```
11E
12C
108N
```

Can I make the original regex do a complete split in one go? Instead of having to run the regex again on the intermediate tokens?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the following regex, and get a list of all matches. That will be what you are looking for.

```
\d+|\D+
```

In Java, I think the code would look something like this:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\D+").matcher(theString);
while (matcher.find())
{
    // append matcher.group() to your list
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also use "[look around](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)" mechanism in regex describing where you want to `split` your text:

```
String stringToSplit = "11E12C108N";
String[] tokens = stringToSplit .split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?=\\d)(?<=\\D)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

output: `[11, E, 12, C, 108, N]`

Idea is to split in places which are between digit (`\d`) and non-digit (`\D`). In other words it is place (empty string) which have:

- digit before `(?<=\d)` and non-digit after it `(?=\D)`

OR

- non-digit before `(?<=\D)` and digit after it `(?=\d)`

More info about `(?<=..)` and `(?=..)` (and few more) you can find at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Even after 12 years this is a really elegant solution. Thanks.