# Split string wherever character class changes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm wondering if there's a [succinct] way to split a string where ever the "class" (e.g. Unicode category, or even simply something like letters/digits/whitespace) of a character changes from one to the next.

For example, something like `"18a.1.50".split(/\b/)` almost works but yields `["18a", ".", "1", ".", "50"]` ("18a" considered a word) instead of `["18", "a", ".", "1", ".", "50"]`.

I'd prefer a solution in JS-compatible regular expression syntax, but I'm also curious for "regular expressions" in general.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not much of a regex wizard, so there are probably better ways, but this seems to work as described.

```
"18a.1.50".match(/\.|\d+|[a-z]+/gi) //["18", "a", ".", "1", ".", "50"]

"18a..b12.1.50".match(/\.|\d+|[a-z]+/gi) // ["18", "a", ".", ".", "b", "12", ".", "1", ".", "50"]
```

Comment: Please let me know if this isn't what you are talking about, I'm not 100% sure, just seemed to fit the criteria -- 'For example, something like "18a.1.50".split(/\b/) almost works but yields ["18a", ".", "1", ".", "50"] ("18a" considered a word) instead of ["18", "a", ".", "1", ".", "50"].'

Comment: In your second example, the `..` character shouldn't be like `["18", "a", ".."`?

Comment: I'm really not sure. It might be, but I wasn't quite positive what the criteria was for splitting. You could change it to `/\.+|\d+|[a-z]+/gi` to do that.

Comment: This is basically the strategy I found too, but instead of the better `\D` you're matching on `[a-z]` instead. I'm wanting something even more general, not just splitting the numbers and letters in the one example but basically any time a character isn't like another.

Comment: I tried the `\D`, it didn't seem to work? `"18a.b12.1.50".match(/\.|\d+|\D+/gi) // ["18", "a.b", "12", ".", "1", ".", "50"]`

Answer (score 1):

Via another question, [Regex split numbers and letter groups without spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232801/regex-split-numbers-and-letter-groups-without-spaces), I found a trick that helps a bit with the practical side of the problem. Basically, there, rather than trying to *split* on the *boundaries*, simply *match* whole *groups* of one class of character. For just letters and numbers it looks something like `"11E12C108N".match(/\d+|\D+/g)` in JavaScript — note the use of `.match()` with a `//g` regex instead of `.split()`.

For the original question, something like `"18a.1.50".match(/\d+|\w+|\W+/g)` would do the trick, albeit won't distinguish between e.g. punctuation vs. symbols vs. control vs. [etc. etc.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm). **UPDATE:** no it doesn't, consider a string like "a18.1.50"! The matching only really can work if all categories are mutually exclusive, which is not the case with most of JavaScript's options.

In summary, this is a little further but still doesn't "scale" to all character classes particularly well without listing them each out (and adding a "non-X" at the end of the final "X" match just in case more get added later). I'm also still curious if it's possible to match the boundaries themselves (i.e. split).

Comment: Realized because `\w` is a super-set of `\d` this doesn't always work…definitely still some general trouble with this approach.

Comment: Instead of character classes, use character ranges to make mutually exclusive ranges: `"18a.1.50".match(/[0-9]+|[A-Za-z]+|^[A-Za-z0-9]+/g)`