# Regex to break non-whitespace string into individual characters and digit chunks in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I've been reading/searching for awhile now, but can't find anything that quite answers my question case.

Currently, I have a string (`str`) such as `"a1bc23def456"` being split using the following regex:

```
 String[] stuff = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
```

which gives me a string array that looks like

```
["a","1","bc","23","def","456"]
```

but what I am trying to get is a split on every character that is a letter, and before a number begins. So that my array will look like:

```
["a","1","b","c","23","d","e","f","456"]
```

so numbers are split from letters, but not from themselves, and letters are split from everything.

I am quite fresh to using regex with Java, so please go easy.

Edit:
This is not quite like the "duplicate" question linked. Because the regex answers provided in that section also result in the same splitting pattern.

I am trying to split groupings of letters. I think it was said well above "*so numbers are split from letters, but not from themselves, and letters are split from everything [including other letters].*"

Comment: Take a look at the linked question, you can have `"(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?=\\d)(?<=\\D)"`

Comment: @Tunaki I ran the code from your comment (and saw the other answer that was linked), and it only splits the characters how I am trying to if they aren't grouped. It would result in the same splitting pattern I said I had in the first place. If you look at my starting regex, you can see they are almost identical.

Not quite a duplicate question. I am asking for something slightly different.

Comment: Ha, so that `"(?=\\D)|(?=\\d)(?<=\\D)"`?

Comment: Duplicate should give you base idea of proper approach. If you take a look at accepted answer then you should see that it is looking for `\\d+|\\D+` which means series of 1 or more digits or non-digits. If you don't want to find series of non-digits because you want to iterate over them one-at-a-time then simply remove `+` after `\\D`.

Comment: @Tunaki, okay now I just feel silly.  Regex has proven to be a little intimidating.

But that last snippet is exactly what I'm looking for. If you like, answer below and I'll award your answer as accepted.

Comment: I am also author of this answer/solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233149/1393766 which you quoted in your question. IMO you could easily adapt it to your needs since it simply means "split in place which has digit before and non-digit after OR non-digit before and digit after". If you also want to split in places which is between non-digits then you could add this condition to your regex like `"...|(?<=\\D)(?=\\D)"` or use shorter version Tunaki already posted in comment.

Comment: @Pshemo, thanks I completely see that now. Thank you so much for your help. I actually used your solution to make most of the original regex I had, and I must of missed the major hint that is now the solution to this question.

Comment: @XavierDass: The question used to close this one is very close, but the objectives are different, and the patterns are different, too. Thus, I reopened this one. The title was misleading, and I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest regex that works is:

```
(?<=\D)|(?=\D)
```

Which splits before or after a letter (`\D` means *non-digit*, which in this context is a letter).

Demo:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a1bc23def456".split("(?<=\\D)|(?=\\D)")));
```

Output:

```
[a, 1, b, c, 23, d, e, f, 456]
```

Comment: note: I marked this answer as correct for it simplicity over the other answers. Alan and Viktor's code works fine, though "(?<=\\D)|(?=\\D)" is just that bit more readable and memorable over "(?!^|(?<=\d)(?=\d))"

Comment: @XavierDass Thank you... I strive for simplicity and "less code" is my mantra. Alan's answer does not actually work. Try it and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the 2 approaches mentioned in a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232801/regex-split-numbers-and-letter-groups-without-spaces):

- Matching single non-digit characters with `\D` or (`|`) digit chunks (`\d+`): `\D|\d+`
- Splitting a string at the locations between a non-digit and a digit (`(?<=\D)(?=\d)`) AND right before a non-digit (`(?=\D)`)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/yZekKT):

```
String str = "a1bc23def456";
String[] stuff = str.split("(?=[^0-9])|(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])");
System.out.println("Split: " + Arrays.toString(stuff));  // => Split: [a, 1, b, c, 23, d, e, f, 456]
// Or match...
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]|[0-9]+").matcher(str);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    result.add(matcher.group(0));
}
System.out.println("Match: " + result); // => Match: [a, 1, b, c, 23, d, e, f, 456]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
(?!^|(?<=\d)(?=\d))
```

It matches anywhere except the beginning of the string or between two digits.  If you're using Java 8, you can leave out the `^|`, because it automatically removes leading empty tokens (same as it always removed *trailing* empty tokens).  Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/TLQ0gW).