# Way to handle string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I would like to remove all digits that come at the start of a string.  I would just like to remove the digits at the start, not at the end or the middle.

Example: "123string67" to "string67"

Is there some function or regex I can use to easily do this?

Comment: *"maybe there is an easy regex command"*. There is. What did you try? Or are you asking us to write the regex for you, without doing *any* research on your own? Down-voted for lack of research.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643142/regex-to-test-if-string-begins-with-http-or-https similar

Comment: regex is your friend... use a pattern for that

Comment: How many digits are allowed to be in the beginning

Comment: use this as a hint...http://stackoverflow.com/q/11232801/982161

Answer (score 1):

You can use [group capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and `^\d*(.*)` regex

```
Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^\\d*(.*)")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("123string67")
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String truncated = matcher.group(); //string67
}
```

Here is a regex explained

```
^    - start of string
\d*  - zero or more digit
 (   - group capture start
  .* - any symbol
 )   - group capture end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint (without regex): (*you still need to consider the case where the string is empty or contains only digits)

```
int i=0;
while(isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
    str.deleteCharAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for ( i.. To i.string.lenght..) and control with ASCII number and delete digit number so you can replaced your string as you want i hope this helpful for you