# Convert String into custom Standard format

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I tried to convert below sample string into different format -

```
String s="MH1BM4";(sample string)
String s="MHA1BM4";(sample string)

String s="MH-01-CM-0004";(o/p)

String s="MH-01-CM-0034";(o/p)

String s="MGH-01-CM-03334";(o/p)

String s="MH-01-CM-03334";(o/p)
```

second place if single digit is present then I need to append -0 and in 
fourth place if less than 4 digit present I need to append -0 accordingly.

Is there anyway to convert it using regx?

Comment: break it out by `StringUtils.isNumeric`, then parse the values.  Then check the length of those values for their position and prepend accordingly

Comment: instead of breaking can i directly convert it into above format using regular expression

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232801/regex-split-numbers-and-letter-groups-without-spaces) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using String.format() for convert numbers to "right" format. For example,

```
String input = "MH1BM4";
String lastSymbol = input.substring(5);
int lastNumber = Integer.parseInt(lastSymbol);
String formattedNumber = String.format("%1$04d", lastNumber);
System.out.println(formattedNumber);
```

out: 0004

More info about formatting here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

And some examples here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/format-java